# Error installing CNTK because of broken git repository

Tags: cntk

We are using an older version of CNTK. I've installed it many times with success. But most recently the error is

```
Submodule 'Source/1BitSGD' (https://git.codeplex.com/cntk1bitsgd) registered for path 'Source/1BitSGD'
Cloning into 'Source/1BitSGD'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.codeplex.com/cntk1bitsgd/': The requested URL returned error: 500
Clone of 'https://git.codeplex.com/cntk1bitsgd' into submodule path 'Source/1BitSGD' failed
```

It looks like the old git repo is no longer there. Has that been repository been removed? And is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1bit repo is still there. It is just that codeplex is flaky. Try again in a little while.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't plan on using 1bitSGD or Multiverso, you should be fine not doing a recursive clone

Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

We are still seeing those codeplex issues....You could create a new clone of the CNTK repository, without the submodules, so something like

Git clone https://github.com/microsoft/cntk

Then you should define the environment variables
CNTK_ENABLE_1BitSGD
CNTK_ENABLE_ASGD
And set them both to false

You should then be possible to build CNTK in your new repo directory. 1bitSGD and Multiverso won’t be available to you, until you remove the environment settings and rebuild

Hopefully the codeplex issues will be solved soon

thx
Wolfgang